# Why is my program not copying the contents of string a to string b? Instead it printing some garbage value

Tags: c, string

The task is to ask user from which character and till where he wants to create another string.

```
int main()
{
    char a[]="Working with stirng is fun";
    printf("%s",a);
    int s,e,j=0; 
    scanf("%d%d",&s,&e);
    char b[e-s+2];
    for(int i=s-1;i<=e-1;i++){
        a[j]=b[i];
        j++;
    }
    a[j]='\0';
    printf("%s",b);
}
```

for eg: if the user enters 4 and 7, the output should be "king".

Comment: Off-topic, but note that if "Working with stirng is fun" is sarcasm... `strncpy(b, a + s - 1, e - s); b[e] = 0;` is much less of a hassle.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be trying to copy a portion of `a` to `b`, but in fact are assigning to elements of `a`.

Comment: Yeah my bad. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

You have your assignment in the loop backwards.  Your a[] variable is the source string and b[] is the destination, but your assignment is `a[j]=b[i];` which assigns b[i] to a[j].  This is a Really Good Example, by the way, of why variable names like a and b are bad.  Had you used variable names like big_string and sub_string you wouldn't have had this problem.  Similarly, names like i and j when you have multiple strings are confusing--big_index and sub_index or some such would be far more clear.

Stylistically, you would do better to keep i and j more closely parallel, instead of declaring and increment i on the for line, and declaring and incrementing j entirely differently:

```
int i, j;
for (i = s - 1, j = 0 ; i <= e - 1 ; i++, j++)
    b[j] = a[i];
b[j] = '\0';
```

seems much cleaner to me.

Better yet, in my opinion, would be to use a single variable to track the number of chars processed, and use it as an offset to the original string and the index to the substring:

```
start--;   // adjust user's input to start at 0 instead of 1
end--;
int dex;
for (dex = 0 ; dex <= end - start ; dex++)
    sub_string[dex] = orig_string[start + dex];
sub_string[dex] = '\0';
```

(I also changed to more clear variable names, and shifted the correction for indexing from 1 to 0 to the variables instead of doing math inside the loop which just adds confusion).

And finally, the easiest way of all to do this is to use the built-in strncpy() function:

```
strncpy(sub_string, &orig_string[start], end - start + 1);
```

Comment: Don't forget that `strncpy` won't terminate your string unless it reaches the end of `orig_string`.

Comment: Okay Thank you. Will make sure to follow your advice in future.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the line
    `a[i] = b[j];` 
to  `b[j]=a[i];`
and  `a[i] = '\0';`
to  `b[j]='\0';`